# Sublime editor shortcut to open command in new window?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have created the following keyboard shortcut in sublime:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+a", "ctrl+m"], "command": "stino_serial_monitor_start" }
```

which works just fine and opens the serial monitor in a new tab. It would be a lot better if I could open this command in a new window. Is it possible to create such a hotkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some time spending on this issue, I have created the following .py file under /CustomCommand, and then linked my shortcut in the original post to "mymacro". The macro name "mymacro" must be all lowercase otherwise it does not work, I guess its some sort of a rule.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class mymacro(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("new_window")
        self.window.run_command("stino_serial_monitor_start")
```

Comment: The name of the class can be anything you want, but Sublime follows rules to convert it to a lower case snake case name; upper case characters are converted to lower case and preceded by an underscore (with no underscore on the first character), and a suffix of `Command` is removed if it exists.  So for example `MyMacro` or `MyMacroCommand` would both become `my_macro`, which was probably your issue.

Comment: This does not work, since the new window isn't selected yet. Add this and it will work:

Comment: (ran out of time so here I try again)
This does not work, since the new window isn't selected yet. Do this instead and it will work: 
self.window.run_command("new_window")
window = sublime.active_window()
window.run_command("stino_serial_monitor_start")